# Underscore Conditionals in Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Here is my template:

```
var tmpl = _.template('<<%= elementTag %> <% if (_.has(elementClass)) { %> class="<%= elementClass %>" <% } %> <%= elementExtra %>><%= template(elementContent) %></<%= elementTag %>>');
```

Some of the objects that I will render using this template my not have an `elementClass` attribute set. I've tried to use `_.has` so that the template only attempts to print the attribute for objects where `elementClass` is defined but I have had no success. The console error states only that `elementClass` is not set, presumably because the conditional statement failed to work as I had intended.

I know this is a simple problem, but I can't seem to solve it - how can I use conditionals in statements like this to detect objects without certain attributes set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, in general, use [`_.isDefined`](http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined) for this. Consider this template:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <% if(!_.isUndefined(elementClass)) { %>
        <%= elementClass %>
    <% } else { %>
        No such thing.
    <% } %>
</script>
```

and this code:

```
var t = _.template($('#t').html());
console.log(t({ }));
```

The call to `t` should give you a ReferenceError because there is no `elementClass` in scope for the compiled template function. So, if your objects don't have an `elementClass` property at all, then the template function will fail when you try to get your template.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/H22D2/

The problem is that the `_.isUndefined` function can only check the *value* of an expression, it cannot check if the variable (or property due to the template's internal [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) usage) you're passing to it has been declared.

If the objects will have an `elementClass` property but it might have an undefined value then you can use `_.isDefined` and this:

```
t({ elementClass: undefined })
```

would be fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LUakg/

If the objects might or might not have `elementClass` properties, then you're stuck using [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) as `typeof` doesn't try to evaluate its operand. Something like this:

```
<script id="t" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <% if(typeof elementClass !== 'undefined') { %>
        <%= elementClass %>
    <% } else { %>
        No such thing.
    <% } %>
</script>
```

will work fine in all three cases of interest:

```
var t = _.template($('#t').html());
console.log(t({ }));
console.log(t({ elementClass: undefined }));
console.log(t({ elementClass: 'pancakes' }));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/H5xC7/

Comment: Any reason in particular you're using `!=` vs. `!==`?

Comment: @Lukas: Not really, `typeof` is defined to return a string so there's no type mangling to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `elementClass` is not `undefined`. (Using `_.isUndefined`, as I previously thought would work, doesn't.)

```
var tmpl = _.template('<<%= elementTag %> <% if ( typeof elementClass !== "undefined" ) ) { print("class=\'elementClass\'") } %> <%= elementExtra %>><%= template(elementContent) %></<%= elementTag %>>');
```

Comment: Yep, good point. I originally had `!== 'undefined'`, but then saw the utility method and though, "hey, that looks nice" but didn't check to see if it worked the same. I edited my answer, the other explains it better.