# How to handle undefined values in the JSON data with Backbone Marionette

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have the following setup:

```
    App.module('TestUsers.Views', function(TestUsersViews, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    TestUsersViews.UsersItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: testUsersItemViewTmpl
        , tagName: 'tr'
        , templateHelpers: {
            handleUndefined: function(val) {
                return (_.isUndefined(val) ? '' : val);
            }
        }
    });

    TestUsersViews.UsersTable = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: testUsersTmpl
        , tagName: 'table'
        , className: 'h-center'
        , itemView: TestUsersViews.UsersItemView
        , itemViewContainer: 'tbody'
        , initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', function() {
                this.appendHtml = function(collectionView, itemView, index) {
                    collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The structure of the Collection returned is:

> [
>    {
>      "apiStandardProfileRequest": {
>        "headers": {
>          "_total": 1,
>          "values": [
>            {
>              "name": "x-li-auth-token",
>              "value": "name:ksBx"
>            }
>          ]
>        },
>        "url": "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/jGEI3X15sx"
>      },
>      "firstName": "Eileen",
>      "headline": "Managing Director of Delivery at Kforce Professional Staffing",
>      "id": "jGEI3X15sx",
>      "industry": "Staffing and Recruiting",
>      "lastName": "Adams (LION)",
>      "location": {
>        "country": {
>          "code": "us"
>        },
>        "name": "Greater Boston Area"
>      },
>      "pictureUrl": "http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_y_g-snorc6G3qFIa->bjSsz4yRb6un3EaOkWSszeCX3-yW5gmr5SOqvpuzEQPz6wGg8x2vtspSH8c",
>      "siteStandardProfileRequest": {
>        "url": "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?>id=3633999&authType=name&authToken=ksBx&trk=api*a249733*s257591*"
>      }
>    },...
>   ]

My template to render the data is:

```
    <td id="<%= id %>"><img src="<%= pictureUrl %>" width="16"      height="16"/><%= firstName %> <%= lastName %></td>   
<td><%= headline %></td>
<td></td>
    <td><%= location.country.code %></td>
    <td><%= location.name %></td>
    <td><a href="<%= siteStandardProfileRequest.url %>">Full Profile</a></td>
```

However, some users do not have a 'pictureUrl' and I get an error of 'Uncaught ReferenceError: pictureUrl is not defined'. I am not sure what I am doing wrong that the undefined value is not handled. I am sure this is an easy fix and any help is appreciated.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283741/ignoring-undefined-data-vars-in-an-underscore-template) is a related question about underscore template's undefined handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer - **override serializeData in Marionette.ItemView**

There are two options. Either check for type undefined in the templates or make sure the data always has the model attributes defined.

The first is cumbersome and adds a lot of clutter to the templates. For the second case one approach as mentioned in other answer is to use model defaults. But that puts another problem.

Model defaults are meant to provide values for attributes which can always have a meaningful value. an example attribute "isValid" can have a default value of true. but there's no meaningful default for "lastName". Setting model defaults for such values have the side effect of saving the defaults to the server, where as your only requirement was to put defaults for views/templates.

To avoid this, you can override serializeData in Marionette.ItemView to add defaults only for rendering.

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  serializeData: function(){
    return _.extend({}, 
      this.model.renderDefaults ? _.result(this.model, 'renderDefaults') : {}, 
      this.model.toJSON()
    );
  }
});
```

In models you can put your defaults for rendering like this

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  renderDefaults : {
    pictureUrl : 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D'
  }
});
```

or

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  renderDefaults : function(){
    return {
      pictureUrl : 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs%3D'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the Marionette-ish `renderDefaults` approach.

Comment: I like this approach and I agree with both your assessments on adding defaults and doing the undefined check in the template. Thanks, this seems like the right way to go.

Comment: Happy to help. Also do notice the pictureUrl default i used. its essentially a placeholder image, which prevents useless server call.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of way to deal with this sort of thing, I'll outline a couple general strategies below.

## In The Template

If you want to handle this inside the template then you'll need to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check if `pictureUrl` exists, anything else will give you a ReferenceError for [reasons I've described elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14325763/479863).

This approach would look like this in your template:

```
<% if(typeof pictureUrl !== 'undefined') { %>
    <img src="<%= pictureUrl %>" width="16" height="16">
<% } %>
```

You might want to say `if(typeof pictureUrl !== 'undefined' && pictureUrl)` if you're expecting empty `pictureUrl` values as well as missing ones.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7bXzf/

You could also add an `else` to that conditional if you wanted to use a standard placeholder avatar, that would probably make your layout a bit prettier and more consistent.

## In The Model

Depending on the precise format of the incoming data, you might be able to use your model's [`defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) to supply a placeholder. Something like this in your model should do the trick:

```
defaults: {
    //...
    pictureUrl: 'url-for-placeholder-avatar-goes-here',
}
```

You could also use `pictureUrl: ''` if you don't want a placeholder but then you'd want to include an `<% if(pictureUrl) { %>` check in your template to avoid invalid HTML.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BZAjJ/

You might have problems with this approach if you're writing the models back to a server for storage.

Comment: Thanks, @mu is too short. I had implemented the first suggestion. However, I would've thought this would be something Backbone, Underscore, or Marioinette can handle and it would adjust for undefined values.

Comment: Underscore's templates are intentionally simple. `_.template` doesn't do much parsing, it just turns the template inside-out to create a JavaScript function and it uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to handle variable look ups. Adding "real" parsing would either change the template language to no longer be embedded JavaScript or it would bloat Underscore with a bunch of parsing code. There are always trade offs.

Comment: @Kianosh: BTW, Mohit's answer might make more sense in a Marionette environment. I won't throw a hissy fit if you switch the accept to his.